# How to construct a locator for the following HTML code?

Tags: list, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I am learning on the xpath philosophy.
Most of the examples found are, in a way, standard and finding xpath manually could be easy.
In the following HTML code, I am not able to understand how should I find the xpath of **Job Duration** and then create a list of elements for li items.

```
<div class="box rounded6">
   <h3 class="s_filter_title">Job Duration :</h3>
   <ul>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="" name="">Contract</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="" name="">Full Time </label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="" name="">Part Time </label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="" name="">Internship</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="" name="">Temporary</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="" name="">Temp To Perm</label></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: refer : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/basics-xpath-pritam-maske/

Comment: refer : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/normalize-space-method-pritam-maske/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you are looking for.

```
//h3[.='Job Duration :']/following-sibling::ul/li//input
```

There are 6 `li` elements in the ul, you can see the count as 6 in the search list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @supputuri. I was able to loop thru the list and print the text of each checkbox. When I try to click on the element from the list, e.click(), it doesn't select any of the check boxes. Any thoughts, please?

Comment: if you want to select the checkbox then you have to add `input` to the xpath, updated the xpath in the answer try with that.

Comment: Thanks @supputuri. I am able to select the check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

To create a *List* of the `<li>` elements associated with the element with text as **Job Duration** you need to identify the element with text as **Job Duration** first and then locate the following `<ul>` node and then locate it's child nodes and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Java* based solution:

  - *xpath1*:

    ```
    List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[text()='Job Duration :']//following::ul[1]//li"));
    ```
  - *xpath2*:

    ```
    List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[contains(., 'Job Duration')]//following::ul[1]//li"));
    ```
- *Python* based solution:

  - *xpath1*:

    ```
    my_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[text()='Job Duration :']//following::ul[1]//li")
    ```
  - *xpath2*:

    ```
    my_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[[contains(., 'Job Duration')]//following::ul[1]//li")
    ```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB. Java based solution with xpath1 also worked.